# How to extract all zip files in nested folders using Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell, zip, unzip

I'm newbie and ask a simple question:
I'm looking for the easiest way to extract all the zip files inside a folder and its subfolders.
and put all of them in a specific folder.

```
e.g.:  
folder-A  
   file1.zip   
   folder-B  
     folder-B file2.zip
     folder-B file3.zip
   folder-C
     folder-D
       folder-D file4.zip
```

I found many topics about this, but I wasn't able to use the solutions proposed
I know that probably I should use `Get-ChildItem` to pass values to Expand-Archive, but I didn't get the result I'm expecting.

I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Toolbase\zip_test\*zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath C:\Toolbase\zip_test\unzipped
```

but the unzipped folder is empty, unless in `C:\Toolbase\zip_test\test2\` there is a zip folder.

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 3):

you are close...you will need to use `recurse` option to iterate through subfolders

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Toolbase\zip_test\*zip -force -recurse | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath C:\Toolbase\zip_test\unzipped -force
```

By default ,`get-childitem` will just check parent directory

Answer (score 1):

The `Expand-Archive` command requires a `-Path` parameter. Currently you're not providing one.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but your desired results would be to have everything unzipped into a different `-DestinationPath`

```
C:.
└───zip_test
    ├───folder-A
    │   │   file1.zip
    │   │
    │   ├───folder-B
    │   │       file2.zip
    │   │       file3.zip
    │   │
    │   └───folder-C
    │       └───folder-D
    │               file4.zip
    │
    └───unziped
```

Since we're passing multiple `System.IO.FileInfo` into the pipeline, we're going to have to loop through every object, and pull the `$_ (Current Object)` full filepath. Then we have to provide the destination path.

Open a PowerShell console and try:

```
     Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Toolbase\zip_test\*zip -Recurse | 
        ForEach-Object { Expand-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath C:\Toolbase\zip_test\unziped }
```

This will provide the following results:

```
C:.
└───zip_test
    ├───folder-A
    │   │   file1.zip
    │   │
    │   ├───folder-B
    │   │       file2.zip
    │   │       file3.zip
    │   │
    │   └───folder-C
    │       └───folder-D
    │               file4.zip
    │
    └───unziped
            file1.txt
            file2.txt
            file3.txt
            file4.txt
```

If you wanted to extract the files in the same directory, you could try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Toolbase\zip_test\*zip -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object { Expand-Archive -Path $_.FullName -DestinationPath $_.Directory }
```

Results would be.

```
C:.
└───zip_test
    ├───folder-A
    │   │   file1.txt
    │   │   file1.zip
    │   │
    │   ├───folder-B
    │   │       file2.txt
    │   │       file2.zip
    │   │       file3.txt
    │   │       file3.zip
    │   │
    │   └───folder-C
    │       └───folder-D
    │               file4.txt
    │               file4.zip
    │
    └───unziped
```

Please update the thread if this answers your question, and if it doesn't, please provide amplifying information.

Comment: You are right  @stim-ca , I would like to unzip all zip files in a different folder: e.g. "unziped". Thank you for providing me the solutions to unzip the files in a specific folder and in the original folders too. Both solutions may be useful to me in the future.